# If the code is correct, why do I get a range check error?

Tags: delphi

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,System.StrUtils;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:integer;
  Cnt:integer;
  s:string;
begin
  Cnt := 0;
  s := Edit1.Text;
  for i := 0 to Length(s) do
    if s[i] =  '.' then
       Cnt := Cnt + 1;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Cnt));
end;

end.
```

After executing the code as above, if I try to find out how many there are,a Range Check Error occurs.

I was checking the example questions. I wonder if there is a problem with the code?

The example is using one TEdit and I was going to make it using one TButton.

Comment: Clearly, you get the error because the code is not correct. It compiles because the syntax is correct, but that does not mean the logic is also.

Comment: @JohnEasley Your comment about -1 is plain wrong in this case.

Comment: A more generic way to treat string loops is: `for i := Low(s) to High(s) do ...`. Or use a `for .. in loop`:  `for C in s do ...`

Comment: As a basic principle, if you get an error, then your code isn't correct. That should always be your starting point. Learning about how strings are indexed is useful but the more important lesson here is to have more self doubt!

Comment: @JohnEasley The problem is not with `to Length(s)` but with `i := 0` Element [0] of a string does not gets you the first char in the string

Comment: Thank you so much for leaving a reply.
It was my first time to learn a language, so I learned it by writing an example code.

But in the example code,
for i := 0 to Length(s) do
I didn't know what was wrong with it

Your answer has helped me a lot Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
for i := 0 to Length(s) do
```

because of some reasons:

`string` characters are numerated from `1` to `Length(s)`, so valid indices for the string of length 3 are `s[1], s[2], s[3]`, and your call to `s[0]` causes range check error.

Delphi/Pascal `for` loop includes both lower and upper range values, so this code tries to make `Length(s) + 1` runs instead of `Length(s)`

[Instances of UnicodeString can index characters. Indexing is 1-based, just as for AnsiString.](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/String_Types_(Delphi)), same refers to other string types except for `PChar` family.

(There is also rarely used compiler option [`{$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS}`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Zero-based_strings_(Delphi)))

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that you can easily realise that the code is wrong even if you have no idea about how Delphi strings are indexed (1-based, 1 to N; or 0-based, 0 to N - 1). How is that? Well, very clearly a loop from 0 to Length(s) is run Length(s) + 1 times. So if the string has 57 characters, you run the loop 58 times. Very obviously wrong, no matter how the strings are indexed!

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand   Thanks. I've already written that Pascal loop includes both borders, now explicitly emphasized that this causes too many iterations.

Comment: Thank you so much for leaving a reply.
It was my first time to learn a language, so I learned it by writing an example code.

But in the example code,
for i := 0 to Length(s) do
I didn't know what was wrong with it

Your answer has helped me a lot Thank you.